# XON/XOFFのフローコントロールを無効にした場合のデメリット

Tags: zsh

Macのターミナル上の`zsh`で`Ctrl+s`で`forward-search-history`を有効にするために

```
stty -ixon
```

でXON/XOFFのフローコントロールを無効にしたのですが、これを無効にした場合どのようなデメリットがあるでしょうか？

wikipediaの該当記事を読むとRS-232のシリアル通信を使わない場合は特に不都合は発生しないようなのですが、他にも何か無効にしてると発生する問題はありますか？
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control

Comment: sttyなんて20年以上使う必要に迫られていませんが、macでは指定しないと駄目だったんですか？ （XONが有効だと、書かれているとおり、端末ドライバがRS-232Cの回線制御をするくらいXOFFで「ちょっとデータを送るの待って！」XONで「データ再開してください」だと思いますので、なにか大事な機能が抑止されることはないと思います）

Comment: 端末でtail -Fやtopを眺めているとき、画面表示を一時的に止めたいときに今も重宝しています。どちらを優先するかはお好みだと思います。

Comment: なるほど、`tail`や`top`で使うこともあるんですね。自分が使ってる範囲では止めてしまっても問題なさそうなのでオフにすることにします。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Macのターミナル上のzshでCtrl+sでforward-search-historyを有効にするために
> stty -ixon
> でXON/XOFFのフローコントロールを無効にしたのですが、これを無効にした場合どのようなデメリットがあるでしょうか？

`ctrl+S`による端末表示停止ができなくなりますが、この機能を利用しないのであれば、端末のXONを無効にしても問題ないと思います。

zshのrcのどれかで次の設定を行うと、XONを無効にできますが、

```
stty -ixon
```

この状態で端末から`stty ixon`を入力すると、元に戻すことができました。
一時的に端末表示停止を使いたいときは`stty ixon`、元に戻す(XONを無効化)するときは`stty -ixon`を実行すればよいので、端末表示停止についても問題ないと思います。

※当初、`stty stop undef`、`stty stop ＾S`で回答していたのですが、不慣れだと制御コードの入力が煩雑なので、質問された方のやり方に変えました。